2018 Community Moderator Election Results
Cryptography's second moderator election has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderators is:

They'll be joining the existing crew shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!
Please join me in thanking mikeazo who is stepping down after 5 years of being a moderator. We're all grateful for his leadership and service.
For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results here, or view a summary report online.

Wow.
I'm not sure what to say.
I guess the usual thing people say in these situation is "thanks". So I shall do the same.
I would like to thank everybody who has put the faith in me to be a good moderator for Crypto.SE. I shall do my best not to disappoint all of you!
I would like to thank the current / "old" moderator team for having done such an excellent job in the past and having inspired me to step up. I shall give my best in working with them!
And of course I would like to thank Mikeazo specifically. He has done an amazing job at moderation over the past 5 years. I'm also grateful for him having served as a moderator across our graduation, as an anchor in times of moderation uncertainity.

Long live potato!

Welcome to the team! <•••>

I'd like to thank Ella and Squeamish for also running in the election. They are doing great work on Crypto, but I'm afraid they were beaten by the potato if not just for the great moderating stats.
Hopefully Ella and Squeamish see this as a challenge to get even better stats; I'll certainly be helping them and, of course, the current mod team with the potato.

It is obvious that there was collusion between the potato administration and the Germans.  You just wait till a special prosecutor roots out all the treasonous side channel dealings obscured by nightshade that made a hash of this election!
